# Comparing two dates one from the database and datetime.now

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and I would like to highlight the days which has difference > 10.

What I have now

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;
            string dateCreated = e.Row.Cells[5].Text;

            DateTime dc = Convert.ToDateTime(dateCreated);
            TimeSpan difference = dateNow - dc;

            if (difference.TotalDays > 0)
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cyan; // This will make row back color red
            }
        }
    }
```

Date format of the one saved onto my database is dd-MM-YYYY and it is saved as nvarchar.

Comment: You should explain what problems do you have with this code. As is, there is no question

Comment: Sorry about it, but my problem is.. it does not highlight the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
int minutes = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(dc).TotalMinutes;
```

or days

```
int days = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(dc).TotalDays;
```

Or seconds, miliSeconds, Weeks, ....

To get date from your string do this:

```
string dateCreated = "01-01-2017";
string[] dcArray = dateCreated.Split('-');
DateTime dc = new DateTime(int.Parse(dcArray[2]), int.Parse(dcArray[1]), int.Parse(dcArray[0]));
```

Comment: How do you suggest that I convert the dateCreated string to?

Comment: It is true what you have done. `DateTime dc = Convert.ToDateTime(dateCreated);`  I must to change my answer dateCreated to dc.

Comment: I edited my answer, it will Defenetly  work how you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse DateTime like that:

```
DateTime dc = DateTime.ParseExact(dateCreated, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I've come across this error "An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code"

Answer (score 0):

Victor Leontyev is right on with the parsing. But then you also have to tweak you logic:

```
if (difference.TotalDays > 0)
```

to

```
if (Math.Abs(difference.TotalDays) > 10)
```